# How do I create radio button for options on a Drupal Commerce product?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, ajax, commerce, javascript

I just need some radio buttons for adding on components in a drupal commerce product. The best example is Apple's build a customized MAC or laptop where you add on specific elements to the product but start with a base. I also need to know how I can do this with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're after either the [Commerce Product Option](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_option) module:

> This module adds customizable product options to the "add to cart" form. The approach is generic, so all field types / widget can be used. This module is created only for the commerce module. For other systems you need different systems / approaches.
>
> The module provides a field called option set. You can assign to your commerce product. Each option set consists of a list of fields. If a product is connected to a option set the add to cart form will be extended by the fields of the option sets.

Or the [Commerce Product Attribute](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) module:

> This module provides some enhancements to the Drupal Commerce attribute handling.
>
> The improvement contains:
>
> Attribute field for line item
>
> Edit option for attributes

I'd advise installing both of those and seeing which fits your use case better. You'll have to handle the AJAX functionality yourself as I don't think it's built in to either.

Comment: any clues on how to create a module for the ajax... I'm brand new with it...